# How to call extreme samples in a Monte Carlo simulation for hypothesis testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sampling, monte-carlo, terminology

For many hypothesis tests, Monte Carlo methods are used to estimate the empirical $p$-value which is defined as $$p=\#{(T_{sample} > T_{observed})}/N.$$ Is there a name for the samples with $T_{sample} > T_{observed}$? And for the samples with $T_{sample} < T_{observed}$?

Comment: "Samples having more/less extreme value of statistic"? I don't think there is any specific term.